# Can iTextSharp reduce dpi resolution of a pdf?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext, resolution, dpi

I'm trying to upload hi-res PDF files to our servers, but would like to generate a smaller PDF file size so that it loads quickly on my web application by reducing the dpi resolution.

Is this something that iTextSharp can do? Or is there another free software that can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

[PDF files, in general, do not have DPI](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5859/all-pdfs-appear-to-be-72-dpi-no-matter-what). Raster images embedded in a PDF file do. What you can do, is to extract the images embedded in your PDF file, resize them to a lower resolution, and put them back in your file.

There is a chapter about this topic in the book [iText in Action](http://www.itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=286).

Comment: YMS, is there a way the file size can be reduced without reducing the image size?

Answer (score 1):

Ghostscript is Free Software (if you want), and it can downsample PDFs any way you want (well, downsample the pixel images that may be embedded on its pages).

Example commandline, which downsamples all images to 72dpi (provided they have a resolution that's more than 144dpi). I'll not use the shortest command, but I deliberately try to enumerate all potentially useful parameters, so that you can experiment:

```
gs \
  -o downsampled.pdf \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
  -dColorImageDownsampleThreshold=2.0 \
  -dGrayImageDownsampleThreshold=2.0 \
  -dMonoImageDownsampleThreshold=2.0 \
  -dColorImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic \
  -dGrayImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic \
  -dMonoImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic \
  -dDownsampleColorImages=true \
  -dDownsampleGrayImages=true \
  -dDownsampleMonoImages=true \
  -dColorImageResolution=72 \
  -dGrayImageResolution=72 \
  -dMonoImageResolution=72 \
  -dAutoFilterColorImages=false \
  -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false \
   \
  -dEncodeColorImages=true \
  -dEncodeGrayImages=true \
  -dEncodeMonoImages=true \
  -dColorImageFilter=/DCTEncode \
  -dGrayImageFilter=/DCTEncode \
  -dMonoImageFilter=/CCITTFaxEncode \
   input.pdf
```

If you want to downsample **all** color images (that is, also the ones from 73dpi to 144dpi), then use `-dColorImageDownsampleThreshold=1.0` (Ghostscript's default is `=1.5`); the same goes for other **ImageDownsampleThreshold* settings.

For the **ImageDownsampleTypes* -- you can also experiment with values of `/Average` or `/Subsample` instead of my suggested `/Bicubic`. And you are of course als free to use different settings for resolution, sampling type and thresholds across the mono, gray and color image types.